# Python - Check how many times a list of numbers is included in a list of lists of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

thank you for helping out

So, I have a list of lists of numbers

```
list1 = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 4]
]
```

Now, I want to check how many times this list:

```
list2 = [3,1,2]
```

is included in the list1

For this example the output should be:

```
2
```

I also tried this:

```
list1 = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 4],
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
]


def removeElements(A, B):
    for i in range(len(B)-len(A)+1):
        for j in range(len(A)):
            if B[i + j] != A[j]:
                break
        else:
            return True
    return False


s2 = [1,2]

count = sum(removeElements(sorted(s2), sorted(lst)) for lst in list1)

print(count)
```

But it doesn't work if s2 = [1,4] as it's checking the numbers in order

If you have an idea or a solution of how that can be achieved, please let me know

Comment: Thank you a lot, I will make sure to follow the steps next time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sum` with a generator expression to count, and `sorted` to compare lists regardless of order:

```
s2 = sorted(list2)

count = sum(s2 == sorted(lst) for lst in list1)
```

Or if you are a functional guy and into one-liners:

```
count = sum(map(sorted(list2).__eq__, map(sorted, list1)))
```

One should remark that this works so neatly because `bool` is a subclass of `int`, and boolean expressions can be summed like integers 0 and 1.

**Update:**
Since you clarified your problem and want to count the supersets (or superlists if there are duplicates), you can use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) subtraction along the same lines:

```
from collections import Counter

c2 = Counter(list2)
count = sum(not (c2-Counter(lst)) for lst in list1)
```

Comment: You are right, it worked as expected, thank you. 

I will accept the answer in 10 minutes (because of cooldown)

Comment: I just tried. This also ignores duplicates. I mean if the target list2 has duplicates, it won't be counted. Perhaps the OP wants that.

Comment: In my case, there is no duplicates on list2

Comment: @nsk Not sure I get you. This considers lists equal that contain the same elements and the same number of each element.

Comment: You are right, I need to see if the list is included not equal. I just tested a smaller array in a bigger one and it doesn't count it

Answer (score 0):

Your problem logic deals with sets, not lists -- the ordering is immaterial.  Convert everything to a set and simply count:

```
set_list = [set(elem) for elem in list1]
```

Now for your target list, simply check how many times it appears:

```
set_list.count(set(target))
```

Comment: This may not work if the involved lists contain duplicates.

Comment: Correct -- perhaps a clarification from OP?

Comment: Of course, if that case can be excluded, `set` should be preferred. But the intermediate list is space inefficient (though probably helpful for the beginner).

Comment: It doesn't work in my case, as I need to see if a list is included, not just equal

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "included" and "equal".  Your sample test case, `[3, 1, 2]` is neither equal nor included in `list1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 4]
]
'''We need to arrange elements in the lists in a one particular way, 
   since [3,1,2] and [1,2,3] are different.
   Hence, sorting all the lists'''
list2 = sorted([3,1,2])

c=0 #Counter variable

for lst in list1:  #Traversing through list1
    lst=sorted(lst)
    
    #From here on, comparing, if there is a list that is equal to list2
    if len(lst)==len(list2):
        flag=0
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            if lst[i]!=list2[i]: 
                flag=1
                break    
        if flag==0:
            c+=1

print(c)
```

Comment: I need to see if a list is included in a list of lists, but your code is checking if they are equal

Comment: Mike, this also checks if list2 is present or not.  If c==0, then list2 is not included in list1. If c!=0, then list2 is present in list1.

Answer (score -2):

```
list1 = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 4],
]

check_list = [3, 5, 2]
count = 0
for l in list1:
    temp = False
    if sorted(check_list) == sorted(l):
        temp = True
    if temp:
        count += 1

print(count)
```

Comment: Do *not* use the name of a built-in type as a variable.  Do not use numerical values in place of Booleans.  Also, please test your code before posting: this doesn't work in general.  For instance, in `check_list`, change the `1` to a `5` and see what happens.

Comment: Correct. This was my first try to answer something. Should not rush myself in. Thanks for the warnings.